# Query to list the row if a certain variable is present in a column

Tags: php, mysql, sql

The query below works fine if the column 'id' has values like 1,2,22, etc. but it has values of the form:1*2*3#7*3#4*5*21#4*3. Now the row should get stored in $row if $x(of the form 1,2,12,etc.) is found in the corresponding column 'id'.How should the query $q be to achieve this?

```
$q=mysqli_query($db,"select * from table1 where id='$x' order by cid DESC");
$row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($q);
```

Comment: Can you please refine your question? I'm not sure what you mean with 1*2*3#7*3#4*5*21#4*3 for example.

Comment: not sure this will work 100% but try using like instead of = ? something in the line of id like '%$x%'??

Comment: the cell stores ids as eg:1*2*3#7*3#4*5*21#4*3 where there can be any number of hashes and there can be any number of ids stored in between them separated by *.

Comment: @Sebastien can you please elaborate about it or provide some link?

Comment: Well if you google MySQL `like` it will tell you that it kinda look for a specifique char in a field. exemple: `select name from person where name like '%b%'` this will return all the names with a 'b'. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like

Comment: Either `like` will do the trick or you will have to parse every id with regex or some other algorithm and trim them from your PHP array.

Comment: @Sebastien I am not getting how to use that here..in my question...I have to list the row if $x is found in the column 'id'(and the column is of the form mentioned above).

Comment: Lets say $x = 5 and your current id = '1*2*5*6#7'. then `SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE id LIKE '%$x%' ORDER BY cid DESC` will return the said id AND all id that contains the character '5'

Comment: You might want to check out the other characters like '%', '_', etc. that can be place inside a like statement in the link provide above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Jump to UPDATE #4 for the solution** (people who should have the same problem)

If i understood your question correct... You want to check if $x is a number? Then replace your provided code with this:

```
if(!preg_match("@[^0-9]@i", $x))
{
    $q=mysqli_query($db,"select * from table1 where id='$x' order by cid DESC");
    $row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($q);
}
```

**EDIT:** What this does is... It checks if the value of the $x variable has any other characters then numbers in it. If it doesn't have any other characters, if it has only numbers then the code inside the if statement will be executed.

**UPDATE:**

I didn't get your question the first time. Let's try again:

```
select * from table1 where id = '$x' AND id NOT LIKE '%#%' order by cid DESC
```

**UPDATE #2:**

```
select * from table1 where id LIKE '%$x%' order by cid DESC
```

**UPDATE #3:**

```
select * from table1 
where 
id LIKE '$x*%' OR 
id LIKE '%*$x' OR 
id LIKE '%*$x*' OR 
id LIKE '%#$x#' OR 
id LIKE '%#$x*' OR 
id LIKE '%*$x#'  
order by cid DESC
```

**UPDATE #4 (if the id is just a number):**

```
select * from table1 
where 
id = '$x' OR 
id LIKE '$x*%' OR 
id LIKE '%*$x' OR 
id LIKE '%*$x*' OR 
id LIKE '%#$x#' OR 
id LIKE '%#$x*' OR 
id LIKE '%*$x#'  
order by cid DESC
```

Comment: No its not that.$x is a php variable of int type that stores id and I want to list those rows whose column 'id'(of the form mentioned in the question) contains the value equal to that of $x.

Comment: If I get the question correctly this wont work because the id will have to match perfectly $x, as I understand that as long as $x is present in the id that row must be return?

Comment: I dont think you got it ..give me chance to explain it again..column 'id' contains multiple ids eg:1*2*3#7*3#4*5*21#4*3 contains ids:1,2,3,4,5,7,21.Now I have to check whether this column contains the id specified by $x.If it does, then store that row in $row

Comment: `AND \`id\` LIKE '%$x%' ` no ?

Comment: @Bob0t Yep this is what i was trying to tell the OP in the question comments

Comment: So how are the different ids separated?

Comment: @Sebastien thats exactly what I want..something like 'contains' may work but I dont know how?

Comment: Then it should work like Sebastien already posted. I have updated my answer as well... But adding multiple ids into one id column is a bad practice anyways... You should create another table and then connect the two with foreign keys.

Comment: @tastro the problem in the solution is that if the column'id' contains 2*3#7*3#4*5*21#4*3 and if $x is equal to 1, the row is still getting returned but it should not.

Comment: That's why i asked how the ids are separated. If for example, they would be separated by a # like this: `#2#3#7#21#1#` then you could do a call like this: `where id LIKE '%#$x#%'`. I will update my answer shortly now that i think that i know what you want. :)

Comment: @user3774008 so `$x` can only be a whole number like 1 or 22? Or can it include # or *? If it can be only a whole number, then the update #3 in my answer should work.

Comment: $x is a whole number like 1 or 22 and the updated answer 3 has a problem that column 'id' can also be simply 1 and not necessarily 1*2 or 1*2#3.